# Fresh installed android studio doesn't build new app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I can't seem to figure out what is happening.

I just installed android studio 3 on my new laptop,
I do all the downloads, I downloaded JDK 8.

Everything seems fine. I then create a brand new application and the build process starts however it fails with all dependencies, I've got all the correct SDK platforms downloaded, as well as SDK tools downloaded,

But this is the messages from the gradle sync:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. 


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1. 


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
```

This is my `Build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and this is my `Build.gradle` for the project:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm not sure the issue because I have a PC running the exact same version of android studio and it works.

Is there anything I could be missing?

Let me know if I need to show more of my settings, but it's simply a fresh install

**EDIT:** I just ran the clean Project and instead got this message now:

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like Android Studio is not able to fetch the dependencies form the repository, because of this error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Do you have a working, direct internet connection? No proxies? Can you access SSL sites like [this test site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) with your browser?

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the test failed on the webiste, this is a work laptop so I will talk with my admin to see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an internet connection issue ... You may check it first.